# How to unsubscribe all observers that watching observable made from 'fromEvent'?

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, observer-pattern, observers, reactive

Let's say I'm iterating the array to make the elements something like this:

```
var containerEl = document.createElement('div');
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

list.map((data) => {
    var divEl = document.createElement('div');
    divEl.innerText = data;

    // Make observer for click
    divEl.onclick$ = fromEvent(divEl, 'click');

    containerEl.appendChild(divEl);
});
```

This should be result something like this:

```
<div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Important thing is that I added onclick$, which is observable:

```
divEl.onclick$ = fromEvent(divEl, 'click');
```

Now I can subscribe onclick something like this:

```
divEl.onclick$.subscribe(...);
```

However what if I redraw the all div elements that created while looping the list array?

To unsubscribe observation, I had to call unsubscribe, which included in returning value of subscription:

```
const a$ = divEl.onClick$.subscribe(...);

...

a$.unsubscribe();
```

That's quite uncomfortable, especially in modular / library development perspective.

Is there a way to unsubscribe all observers from divEl.onclick$ in this case?

Any advice will very appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe use "takeUntil" operator like

```
private unsubscriber$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
const a$ = divEl.onClick$.takeUntil(this.unsubscriber$).subscribe(...);

---
// you want to unsubscribe 

this.unsubscriber$.next(true);
this.unsubscriber$.unsubscribe();
```

Every observable on which you use takeUntil operator , will unsubscribe when you change the value inside the "unsubscriber$" observable

Comment: You are my life saver. Thanks dude!!